# How do I check if an EVP_PKEY contains a private key?

Tags: c, openssl, cryptography, private-key

OpenSSL has the higher-level `EVP_PKEY_*` functions which work across all the pubkey-key cryptography algorithms.  However, sometimes a `EVP_PKEY*` only has a public key.  How could I check if a `EVP_PKEY*` contains a private key?  I could use `EVP_PKEY_decrypt_init` and see if it returns an error, but that seems to be quite heavy-handed for what seems to be a simple check.

Comment: OpenSSL makes me cry. The lack of a function to do something as simple as this is one of the (many) reasons.

Answer (score 2):

I am working with EC keys and had to do just this, but it will not work for the general case. I am not even sure if it is correct to do it this way. I have two files, one with a private key and one with a public key. I load those files, retrieve and verify the `EC_KEY`, and attempt to get the private key and the public key from the `EC_KEY`.

A general overview of the process is:

```
// private key:
PEM_read_PrivateKey      // load private key
EVP_PKEY_get1_EC_KEY     // EVP_PKEY to EC_KEY
EC_KEY_check_key         // validate key (OK)
EC_KEY_get0_private_key  // if result is not NULL: has private key (OK)
EC_KEY_get0_public_key   // if result is not NULL: has public key (OK)

// public key (only thing that changes is LOAD function):
PEM_read_PUBKEY          // load public key
EVP_PKEY_get1_EC_KEY     // EVP_PKEY to EC_KEY
EC_KEY_check_key         // validate key (OK)
EC_KEY_get0_private_key  // if result is not NULL: has private key (false)
EC_KEY_get0_public_key   // if result is not NULL: has public key (OK)
```

Note that when we read the private key, it appears to populate both the private key and the public key whereas when we read the public key it only populates the public key parameters. I suppose this is has expected.

---

### Validate `EVP_PKEY` and check whether it has public/private keys

This only works for type `EVP_PKEY_EC` but can be extended to support others. We would call `validate_pkey`, the rest would be internal support functions one for each type of key.

```
static int validate_pkey_ec(EVP_PKEY *pkey)
{
    int result = 0;

    EC_KEY *ec_key = EVP_PKEY_get1_EC_KEY(pkey);
    if (!ec_key)
        return -1;

    if (1 != EC_KEY_check_key(ec_key)) {
        EC_KEY_free(ec_key);
        return -1;
    }

    if (EC_KEY_get0_private_key(ec_key))
        result = 2;

    if (EC_KEY_get0_public_key(ec_key))
        result++;

    EC_KEY_free(ec_key);

    return result;
}

/**
** Performs sanity checks on the given EVP_PKEY.
**
** Returns 1, 2, or 3 when valid:
**   - Returns 1 if only public key is present.
**   - Returns 2 if only private key is present.
**   - Returns 3 if both public and private keys are present.
**/
int validate_pkey(EVP_PKEY *pkey)
{
    int key_type = EVP_PKEY_type(pkey->type);

    switch (key_type) {
    case EVP_PKEY_RSA:
    case EVP_PKEY_DSA:
    case EVP_PKEY_DH:
        // not implemented
        return -1;
    case EVP_PKEY_EC:
        return validate_pkey_ec(pkey);
    default:
        // unknown type, NID_undef?
        return -2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just check if the `EVP_PKEY` object has the necessary params, like private key exponent.

```
if (Key->pkey.rsa->d)
 printf("I have a private key");
```

I'm not sure if a more universal method exists to handle other three algorithms in one line, but it's easy to write your own function based on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx = NULL;
ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_from_pkey(NULL, pkey, NULL);
if (EVP_PKEY_public_check(ctx)) {
    printf("I have a public key");
}

if (EVP_PKEY_private_check(ctx)) {
    printf("I have a private key");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**